# php simple regex search and replace and shuffle substring

Tags: php, regex, latex

i have a string to be used for latex later the string is... roughly

```
$string  = "\\sin\\left(x\\right)^{2}";
```

where the sin could also be cos, tan, sec, log, etc.. 
the exponent could also be any integer, float or variable, the argument could be anything..

I would like a regex function that turns it into

```
$string  = "\\sin^{2}\\left(x\\right)";
```

or more generally

```
generalstring = "f(t)^{n}";
```

to be turned into `"f^{n}(t)";` 
my apologies in advance, i have a feeling this should be extremely easy to do, I'm just learning this.

oh also i would like to restric this to only strings with trig functions logs and some other ones where my functions are not printing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\\\\(\w+)\\\\left\\((.+?)\\\\right\\)\\^\\{([^}]+)\\}/','\\\\$1^{$3}\left($2\right)',$string);
```

For me, the output is:

```
print "$string\n";

\sin^{2}\left(x\right)
```

Another test:

```
$string  = "\\cos\\left(3x\\right)^{2.6}";
```

Output:

```
\cos^{2.6}\left(3x\right)
```

It also works for multiple functions, since `preg_replace` is **global** per default.

```
$string = "\\sin\\left(x\\right)^{3}\\cos\\left(y\\right)^{2}";

\sin^{3}\left(x\right)\cos^{2}\left(y\right)
```

Edit: Please note the corrected expression.

Comment: sorry @Nemesis this breaks in case string contains more than one such function such as $string = "\\sin\\left(x\\right)^3\\cos\\left(y\\right)^2"; is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: The problem are not the two functions, but that you used `^3` instead of `{^3}`. From your question it looked like that you always include the exponent in bracets.

Comment: I just saw, the output was wrong. Let me think about again.

Comment: you are correct.. i meant with brackets.. i will fix the comment  now should be $string = "\\sin\\left(x\\right)^{3}\\cos\\left(y\\right)^{2}"  i think this breaks the function..

Comment: @userX Should be correct now also for more than one function.

Answer (score 0):

A regex like

```
(\\{2}sin|cos|tan|sec|log)([^^]*)(\^\{[^}]*\})
```

see how the regex matches http://regex101.com/r/iW4pZ3/1

The replacement string is `\\1\\3\\2`

```
preg_replace("/(\\\\{2}sin|cos|tan|sec|log)([^^]*)(\\^\\{[^}]*\\})/","\\1\\3\\2","\\\\sin\\\\left(x\\\\right)^{2}");
```

would produce an output as

```
\\sin^{2}\\left(x\\right)
```

Comment: i dont know i did not downvote it i appreciate your help.. however i am trying    $string  = "\\sin\\left(x\\right)^{2}";

echo preg_replace("/(\\\\{2}sin|cos|tan|sec|log)([^^]*)(\\^\\{[^}]*\\})/","\1\3\2",$string); and it outputs the same string as initial string.. maybe iam doing something wrong..

Comment: it works on the regex101 link but not on my machine.. i must have some syntax error or something as such..

Comment: @userX sorry i did some wrong in escaping the `\1\3\2` it should be `\\1\\3\\2` corrected in the answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your help @nu11p01n73R its working now except only when I add stashes to my original string.. is there an easy way to modify so that the input is the original string?

Comment: @userX yes. Use single quotes instead of double quotes